# Loop that changes a date, copy & pastes resulting data, then continues these processes

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has a column with a series of dates that are the same day in a sequence of years (for example 5/1/1986, 5/1/1987, 5/1/1988, ... 5/1/2017).

When the first date at the top of the column is changed (for example from 5/1/1986 to 5/2/1986), all of the other years below will update to that given day and a series of data will be produced in two separate columns through a calculation that is depends on the day as a variable.

The 2nd worksheet has two tables where I need the data resulting from each day between 5/1 and 8/28 for 1986 - 2017 to be pasted from the 1st worksheet after the date is changed (5/1 to 5/2 to 5/3) and so on. The tricky part is the copy and paste needs to happen each time before the date is changed in order to record all of the subsequent data.

I know that I will likely need to use a DateAdd function to loop the addition of one day to the starting date at the top of the column, and I know that I will probably need to utilize a Do Until function to have the sequence stopped when the final date of 8/28 is input. I have been tweaking around the code but I cannot get the formatting correct.

To clarify I need a loop that will do two processes, add one day to 5/1/1986 (until 8/28) and copy the data that each change of day yields and paste it into a 2nd worksheet, before the date is changed again and new data appears. Thanks.

Below is the code I wrote that successfully sets up the first step of the process, setting the start date to 5/1/1986 and copying and pasting the data into the tables in sheet2.

```
'StartDate is input as 5/1/1986 and plugged into first cell of data range, DK7'
Dim StartDate As String
StartDate = Range("DO50").Value
    Range("DK7").Value = StartDate

'EndDate is input as 8/28/1986 and used as reference to end sequence of Copy & Pasting'
Dim EndDate As String
EndDate = Range("DO51").Value

'Corn Z-Score results for StartDate are copied and pasted into Sheet2'
Range("DS7:DS38").Copy
Worksheets(2).Range("D4:D36").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Soy Z-Score results for StartDate are copied and pasted into Sheet2'
Range("DT7:DT38").Copy
Worksheets(2).Range("D41:D73").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: on sheet2, are you pasting different days into different columns ?

Comment: you do not need to add dates in VBA. let cell formula do that. example: `B2 contains date 5/1/1986` . `C1 contains 0` . `C2 formula =B2 + C1` . `C3 formula   =DATE(YEAR(C2)+1,MONTH(C2),DAY(C2))` ... (increments by one year on each row) ... copy C2 and paste into C3 all way to C40 ... format C2 to C40 as date ... now increment C1 (vba code would just increment C1)

Comment: @jsotola yes, on sheet2 I am pasting the data that results from changing the day in the firs cell of the date column on sheet1 into different columns in sheet2 (one column for every day 5/1/1986 through 8/28/1986). And I'm not sure I can do what I want to do without VBA because I need to repeat the process of changing the value of the first cell of the date column in sheet1 to the next day, copying and pasting the data that results into the respective column on sheet2, and then move on to the next day.